# I18n usage in CQ5

Tags: aem

I added i18n to my component title in cq5.4.But I am unable to changed the content author's language preference to fr.How to do that.And is there a way to change the content of the webpage in the desired language in CQ5.4

Answer (score 2):

To set a language preference for a user:

1. from the Welcome screen, click the Users button; the User
   Administration and Security UI is launched;
2. in the panel at the
   left, click the name of the user for whom you wish to set a language
   preference;
3. click the Preferences tab;
4. make a selection from the
   Language dropdown;
5. click Save.

Typically, internationalized CQ5 websites divide into language-specific nodes directly below the website root.  Look at the Geometrixx example site, where there is content/geometrixx/en, content/geometrixx/de, content/geometrixx/fr, etc.

Feike Visser has a short blog post on a [translation tool](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/12/using-the-i18n-translator.html).  In a typical local development environment, the tool is at `http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/i18n/translator.html`.